# Conditional JOIN produces two many rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to join two tables like these:

Table A

```
A1, A2, A3
A, 1, 35
A, 1, 70
A, 1, 105
```

Table B

```
B1,B2, B3
B, 1, 30
C, 1, 32
D, 1, 40
E, 1, 55
F, 1, 60
G, 1, 77
H, 1, 80
```

The expected result is like this:

```
A, 1, 35, C, 32
A, 1, 70, F, 60
A, 1, 105, H, 80
```

That is, for every row in table A, I want to pick just one row from table B, which should be the row with the value of B3 smaller, but closest to the value of A3.

So far, I have tried the following query:

`SELECT A1, A2, A3, B1, B3  FROM A JOIN (SELECT B1, B2, B3  FROM B ORDER BY B2, B3 DESC) AS A ON A.A2 = B.B2 AND A.B3 < A.A3`

However, this results in a table as follows:

```
A, 1, 35, B, 30
A, 1, 35, C, 32
A, 1, 70, B, 30
A, 1, 70, C, 32
A, 1, 70, D, 40
A, 1, 70, E, 55
```

and so forth.  I also tried to add a LIMIT 1 to the inner SELECT, but that does not produce any results.  If I run the inner query by itself (with LIMIT 1), I do get the expected result.  How can I change the query to produce the desired result?  I am using sqlite at the moment, but would like to write this in a way that is portable to other DBMS.

Comment: `ORDER BY` in the sub query makes no sense.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can also create an SQL fiddle to help us help you with complex questions.

Comment: Thanks.  I clarified my question, since I do not want the absolutely closest value, but the one smaller but closest to the value in Table A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have SQLite available, but the following works in SQL Server; you should be able to replace TOP with LIMIT.

You should be able to get it from a nested query in the select, as long as you specify TOP 1:

```
select *, 
   (select top 1 B3 
    from B 
    where B3 <= A3
    order by B3 desc)
from A
```

EDIT: To add the extra column from B requires you to nest the above query into a subquery:

```
select t.*, B.B1 from (
select *, 
   (select top 1 B3 
    from B 
    where B3 <= A3
    order by B3 desc) as B3
from A
) as t join B on B.B3 = t.B3
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that gives me almost what I asked for and it is surprisingly simple. However, in my question I am returning 2 values from the "correlated subquery" but with this solution, it seems that the way this is written I can only as for one value from Table B -- What should I do if I also want to have b.b3 in my return table?

Comment: I added an edit above to show getting that second value from B; it's a little tidier if you can use a CTE, but unfortunately that's not an option in SQLite.

Comment: This is great, I would never have thought of that!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT 
  a.A1,
  a.A2, 
  a.A3,
  (
    SELECT b.B3
    FROM TableB AS b
    ORDER BY ABS(a.A3 - b.B3)
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS x
FROM TableA AS a;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/978af/21)

SQL Fiddle wouldn't let me use sqlite cause my browser doesn't support it, so I hope this works for you.

**EDIT:** This should actually give you the closest value. 77 is closer to 70 than 60... but I don't know if this is exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Given that all entries in `TableA` should be unique, the `GROUP BY` is not necessary.

Comment: SQLite does not have `TOP`.

Answer (score 1):

When you want exactly one row from the initial table, then you can think about using a subquery in the `select` clause:

```
select a.*,
       (select b3
        from TableB b
        where b.b3 <= a.a3
        order by b3 desc
        limit 1
       ) as b3
from TableA a
```

The subquery itself is called a "correlated subquery", because the `where` clause references both the inner table (`b`) and the outer table (`a`).  It orders the table b results by b3, filtering out all but the values less than or equal to `a.a3` in each row.  The `limit 1` returns a single value, which because of the sort is the closest value less than or equal to the value in `a.a3`.

Your question says the closest value, but the example results have the greatest value less than or equal to.